# how to show always a view in the screen

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I have this XML for a Activity and I want to show always Gallery view in the screen.When I use this layout and ListView goes bigger Gallary goes under the ListView and out of visible.How can show it always in the screen even ListView goes bigger than the screen size? Using this layout or another type.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" > 

<ExpandableListView 
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ExpandableListView>

<Gallery 
    android:id="@+id/gallery_footer_row"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"        

     />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical" > 

<ExpandableListView 
android:id="@+id/listView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1">
</ExpandableListView>

<Gallery 
android:id="@+id/gallery_footer_row"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"        
 />
</LinearLayout>
```